# Develop remote desktop connect android app for windows or linux system

Tags: android, linux

I want to develop remote desktop connectn app in android to connect linux or windows system. I dont have any idea from where to start proceeding. provide me some API of plan how can i do this since iam new to android. this is my project work in a course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your experience is with software development as a whole, but you're going to need the computer you plan to remote desktop to to be running a remote connection server such as VNC and then you'll need to create a socket connection to that server from Android and pass messages to the server for the things you want it to do.  Without a library, which I don't know of any, this is going to be a huge undertaking and you might want to consider a smaller project if you have never done anything in Android before.